# Tap operator - Why an Observable expanded by other 2 observables trigger tap 2 times instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs6

From the following code:

```
const parent$ = interval(2000).pipe(
  map(x => 'parent' + x),
  tap(_ => console.log('click$'))
);

const child$ = parent$.pipe(map(x => x + ' from child 1'));
const child2$ = parent$.pipe(map(x => x + ' from child 2'));

child$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
child2$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

I expected this output:

```
click$
parent0 from child 1
parent0 from child 2
...
```

Instead the correct output is:

```
click$
parent0 from child 1
click$
parent0 from child 2
...
```

Why click$ tap emits twice?

Implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gpxoud?devtoolsheight=60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the output you have because it runs through and fires the `tap` side effect for each subscribe.

in order to get the output that you expected, you would need to add a `shareReplay`

```
const parent$ = interval(2000).pipe(
  map(x => 'parent' + x),
  tap(_ => console.log('click$')),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

This way, each subscriber to the `parent$`  observable are "sharing" the emission from the `parent$` observable. Tap is only called once, then.

you can see it in a stack blitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rvymjx

Comment: So this means that without `shareReplay(1)` operator when I split an observable it is split from the root source. In order to share part of a stream it must be declared, isn't it?

Comment: The above observables are the same as a youtube video. every time you subscribe to it, it's the same as opening a new browser tab and starting the video from the beginning.

Comment: When we add `shareReplay` it's more like we are sharing a live version of the obeservable so all subscribers are watching the same youtube video, at the same time in the same browser tab

Comment: I hope that helps.

Comment: Works well! I added after `shareReplay` `takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)`... it is good to always unsubscribe especially for big apps that can have performance issues. Don't forget to define `private unsubscribe = new Subject<void>();` and then at the end of the function call these two after each other: `this.unsubscribe.next();`
`this.unsubscribe.complete();`

Answer (score 0):

to understand better what is happening this code may help you

```
    let i = 0;
    const parent$ = interval(2000).pipe(
        map((x) => `parent ${x} - ${i++}`),
        tap((_) => console.log('click$')),
    );

    const child$ = parent$.pipe(map((x) => x + ' from child 1'));
    const child2$ = parent$.pipe(map((x) => x + ' from child 2'));

    child$.subscribe(console.log);
    child2$.subscribe(console.log);
```

you see that parent gets triggered for every subscribe